# Find duplicates, keep first and replace rest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains duplicate values in columns, I need to identify the duplicates, keep the first and replace the others, could be zero or NaN

Here is an example of the df

| id | Tables | Industry | Logistic | Comercial | Feedback | Return | Finished |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 166 | 325158.0 | NaN | None | 2140957.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 379 | 161616.0 | 417296.0 | None | 1808454.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 136 | 1729.0. | 417296.0 | None | 1734326.0 | NaN | 217 |
| 4 | 1173 | 174533.0 | 417296.0 | None | 1734188.0 | NaN | 217 |
| 5 | 111 | 1531.0 | 406413.0 | None | 1714706.0 | NaN | 217 |

Expected result:

| id | Tables | Industry | Logistic | Comercial | Feedback | Return | Finished |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 166 | 325158.0 | NaN | None | 2140957.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 379 | 161616.0 | 417296.0 | None | 1808454.0 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 136 | 1729.0. | None | None | 1734326.0 | NaN | 217 |
| 4 | 1173 | 174533.0 | None | None | 1734188.0 | NaN | None |
| 5 | 111 | 1531.0 | 406413.0 | None | 1714706.0 | NaN | None |

Comment: "I tried the .duplicated but didn't work well" What _specifically_ did you try, what was your output, and what was wrong with that output? Please [edit] to make a [mcve]

Comment: Will you please add another sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I adjusted the desired output. About the .duplicated,  I was trying something similar to what @Paul responded but with some logic mistakes. Thanks for the heads up on questions patterns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To, for example, replace the duplicates in the Logistic column, first find the duplicates:

```
df.Logistic.duplicated()
```

By default, `keep = ‘first’` (more info about [pd.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html))

So when you localize al duplicates using .loc, you can easily replace them:

```
df.loc[df.Logistic.duplicated(), 'Logistic'] = None
```

A for-loop can do this trick for all your columns:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col_name].duplicated(), col_name] = None
```

If anyone has a more elegant way to do it for all columns, would love to see it :)